# How to generate constant pool index when java compile

Tags: java, jvm

I`m interested in java class file (.class)
if we see .class file using javap, can see Constant pools infomation.

```
#4 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
#5 = Utf8               <init>
#6 = Utf8               ()V
#7 = Utf8               Code
```

There are index #1,#2,#3,#4,#5, #6.......

java compiler will be genreate these index...
Is there rules to generate index number?  is it random number?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there rules to generate index number?

If you mean, are the rules specified (in the JVM spec), then answer is No.

> is it random number?

No.  If you delved deeply into the compiler source code, etc you would *in theory* have sufficient information to predict the index values of the constant pool entries.  The allocation of indexes looks random, but it is (I think) totally deterministic and repeatable.

However, predicting the indexes for an arbitrary Java program (without compiling it!) is unlikely to be practical.

Comment: Predicting the indexes for an arbitrary Java program is possible by compiling the program and reading back the indexes.

Comment: @Robert3452 - Obviously.  We are talking about predicting without compiling.

Comment: My point was that there reverse engineering the compiler to come up with the algorithm to generate the indexes is functionality the same as just running the compiler and calling that a prediction. Depending on why the questioner needs to know the index it may be an acceptable solution to the problem.

Comment: It is not "the same".  It is 2 different processes that produce the same result.  Besides, I suspect that the questioner doesn't *need* to know at all.  (Or if he believes he does, that there is a better way of doing ... whatever he is trying to do.)